# Call coroutine within Thread

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to make a thread run method async so it can execute coroutines inside it? I realise I am mixing paradigms - I am trying to integrate a 3rd party library that uses coroutines whereas my project uses threads. Before I consider updating my project to use coroutines instead I'd like to explore executing coroutines within my threads.

Below is my example usecase where I have a thread but I want to call a coroutine from within my thread. My problem is the function `MyThread::run()` doesn't appear to be executing (printing). Is what I am trying possible...and advisable?

```
from threading import Thread

class MyThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)

        self.start()

    # def run(self):
    #   while True:
    #       print("MyThread::run() sync")

    async def run(self):
        while True:
            # This line isn't executing/printing
            print("MyThread::run() sync")

            # Call coroutine...
            # volume = await market_place.get_24h_volume()


try:
    t = MyThread()

    while True:
        pass
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a asyncio event loop, and wait until the coroutine complete.

```
import asyncio
from threading import Thread


class MyThread(Thread):
    def run(self):
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()  # loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(self._run())
        loop.close()
        # asyncio.run(self._run())    In Python 3.7+

    async def _run(self):
        while True:
            print("MyThread::run() sync")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            # OR
            # volume = await market_place.get_24h_volume()


t = MyThread()
t.start()
try:
    t.join()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. When I run the code, no print output is shown. However if I comment out `await asyncio.sleep(1)` it does show the print output `MyThread::run() sync` many times so the thread is running. Can you explain whats going on? Why wouldn't it print with the code `await asyncio.sleep(1)`?

Comment: @JakeM It prints `MyThread::run() sync` for me with ..sleep..   Which version of python are you using?  I tested with 3.6.1.

Comment: I think this is missing a `set_event_loop` call.

Comment: @astrojuanlu, The code works with `set_event_loop`. Maybe you should mention OP so that he or she is notified.